# How to properly overlap text over an image

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble having my text display only within my image. It's dependent on the length of the text, if it's two rows long, then it'll display correct. Any longer it'll extend past the image. I can fix this by setting the `bottom: 25px;` for my `featured_wrapper` but I don't think that's a `Good` fix. If the text is only 2 rows long then that it sets the text higher than it should. May I ask how should I properly set the text so that it'll always remain within the image.

```
<div id="featured_item">
  <a href="http://bandwagonbible.com/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs" id="featured_link">
    <picture id="featured_picture">
      <img src="http://bandwagonbible.com/Stories/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs/Image2.jpg" id="featured_image" alt='' />
    </picture>
    <div id="featured_wrapper">
      <h3 id="featured_title">
        A Beginners Guide To Getting Six Pack Abs ... add in some more text
      </h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZVdpq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the height to auto in your `#featured_wrapper` rule

```
#featured_wrapper {
    bottom: -2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(40, 173, 230);
    height: auto;                 /*  <---  changed to auto  */
```

```css
#featured_item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    height: 173.813px;
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    width: 309.297px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    perspective-origin: 154.641px 86.9063px;
    transform-origin: 154.641px 86.9063px;
    border: 0px none rgb(34, 34, 34);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 24px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 21px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(34, 34, 34) none 0px;
}

#featured_link {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(40, 173, 230);
    display: block;
    height: 173.813px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 309.297px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    perspective-origin: 154.641px 86.9063px;
    transform-origin: 154.641px 86.9063px;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(40, 173, 230);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 24px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(40, 173, 230) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 173.813px;
}

#featured_picture {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(40, 173, 230);
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border: 0px none rgb(40, 173, 230);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 24px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(40, 173, 230) none 0px;
}

#featured_image {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(40, 173, 230);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 173.969px;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 309.297px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    perspective-origin: 154.641px 86.9844px;
    transform-origin: 154.641px 86.9844px;
    background: rgb(245, 245, 245) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(40, 173, 230);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 24px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(40, 173, 230) none 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#featured_wrapper {
    bottom: -2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(40, 173, 230);
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    width: 289.297px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    perspective-origin: 144.641px 45px;
    transform-origin: 104.641px 45px;
    border: 0px none rgb(40, 173, 230);
    font: normal normal normal normal 16px / 24px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    outline: rgb(40, 173, 230) none 0px;
}

#featured_title {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    position: relative;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    width: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: normal normal normal normal 22px / 22px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="featured_item">
  <a href="http://bandwagonbible.com/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs" id="featured_link">
    <picture id="featured_picture">
      <img src="http://bandwagonbible.com/Stories/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs/Image2.jpg" id="featured_image" alt='' />
    </picture>
    <div id="featured_wrapper">
      <h3 id="featured_title">
        A Beginners Guide To Getting Six Pack Abs ... add in some more text
      </h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I don't think you need all that CSS/markup either, so here is a shortened version for you.

```css
#featured_item {
    position: relative;
    width: 309.297px;
    margin: 0px 21px 0px 0px;
}

#featured_link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#featured_image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

#featured_title {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961);
    font: normal 22px / 22px ProximaNovaCond, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="featured_item">
  <a href="http://bandwagonbible.com/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs" id="featured_link">
    <img src="http://bandwagonbible.com/Stories/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs/Image2.jpg" id="featured_image" alt='' />
    <div id="featured_title">
      A Beginners Guide To Getting Six Pack Abs ... add in some more text
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @LGSon, Fantastic answer!!! This is for my recommended section of my webpage, so I'm trying to have the image just a tad smaller than normal so I can stack them one ontop of eachother

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height: 50px;` in the `#featured_wrapper` rule and also change the `bottom:2px;` to 0 to make it be stick to the bottom.

[Like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqeGGQ)

I also change the `display:inline` of the text and add a `width:100%` to make the text adapt the full width of the image.